# HTML5 Video - double click to go full screen

Tags: html, video, fullscreen

I wish to have my video go full screen when the user double clicks the video area, not just when they click the small icon in the controls. Is there a way to add an event or something to govern what happens when the user clicks the video?

```
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="/v/foo.mp4">
</video>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may experiment with this : http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-full-screen-api/

Answer (score 3):

As Musa suggested, attach a double click event--something like `$('video').on('dblclick', callback)`

`element.requestFullScreen` is probably the "proper" way to do it, but browser support [isn't great yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen), especially on mobile.

If you don't need true full screen, and filling the browser would suffice, you could apply some CSS inside the `dblclick` callback.

Answer (score 2):

Attach a double click(`dblclick`) [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to the video, then in the listener call [requestFullScreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.requestFullScreen) on the video.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a working example:**

https://fiddle.jshell.net/AhmadMysra/57kcyhbp/4/

```js
function makeFullScreen(divObj) {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement && // alternative standard method
    !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
    if (divObj.requestFullscreen) {
      divObj.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (divObj.msRequestFullscreen) {
      divObj.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (divObj.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      divObj.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (divObj.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      divObj.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
      console.log("Fullscreen API is not supported");
    }

  } else {

    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<video controls style="border: 1px solid blue;" height="360" width="480" ondblclick="makeFullScreen(this)">

<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">

 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm">
  
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg"><!-- Firefox3.6+ / Opera 10.5+ -->
    
    </video>
<p>
  Hosting of the video provided by<br>
  <a href="http://webop.de/users/69">André M. Åslund</a> of <a href="http://vorwaerts-gmbh.de">Vorwärts GmbH</a>.
</p>
```

Comment: Worked for me tks

Answer (score 1):

```
<video controls autoplay ondblclick="fullScreen()">
  <source src="/v/foo.mp4">
</video>

<script  type='text/javascript'>
  function fullScreen() { 
    if (!window.isFs) $(".mejs__fullscreen-button > button").trigger('click');
    else  $(".mejs__unfullscreen > button").trigger('click'); 
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html) can help you, there are also much HTML5 / JavaScript players to use (Excemple: [BuckPlayer](http://buckplayer.com)). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you but I can't find how to make the browser do something when the user clicks the actual area in which the video is. I just want it to go full screen when the user clicks or double clicks it.